# When is it necessary or beneficial to specify a custom Machine Key in web.config? (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I've come across a couple of open source applications which recommend or require that a custom machine key is specified in web.config.

Why would this be necessary?

What is the reason, or advantage in specifying a custom machine key in web.config?

Answer (score 1):

The first place a website search for configuration is Machine.config. Then Web.config overrides it.

Here are few reasons.

1. When you do Encryption and Decryption for example you can specify the keys in Machine key. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.100).aspx) and [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772271(v=ws.10).aspx)
2. And, if you need to share a value between multiple websites hosted on the same server.